# UWA Print Dialog Box in Win32 - with UWA dialog crashes, with Win32 dialog never

Tags: c, winapi, printing

**I have a 30 year old print dialog routine**

It is only upgraded for UTF16 characters (WCHAR), that always worked based on the sequences:

```
if ((S_OK == PrintDlgEx(&pdPrint)) && pdPrint.dwResultAction == PD_RESULT_PRINT && pdPrint.hDC) {
if (StartDoc(pdPrint.hDC, &diPrint) == SP_ERROR) {
```

***Suddenly I installed an Office 2021*** in one of my computers and ***the Win32 Print dialog changed to a UWA Print dialog (layout)***, and the title:

- Is not just the usual "Print"
- But "Printing from a Win32 program - Print".

It is obvious that MS office installs another print dialog and it has other parameters that the regular PrintDlgEx does not support, kind of conversion.

**The Problem - StartDoc() crashes**

It is crashing by StartDoc() with

```
"Exception thrown at 0x00007FFAE6406BC in XXXXXX.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: winrt::hresult_error at memory location 0x000000371555C4D0."
```

And there is absolutely no debugging by StartDoc(), it's under the hood. But remarkably also is that there are nothing the program allocates memory for, it all comes from the print dialog.

Same code in my laptop with Office 2008 installed, still Win32 Print dialog and no problem.

As far as I know no changes made (except Win 11 22H2 upgrades and VS Upgrade to 17.4.3 but still v143) to the version distributed in MS Store (by me), it does not crash in any of my computers.

**What to do about it?**

The basic problem is that I, as a SW supplier via the MS Store, have no control over which programs my customers install in their computer next to my program. (I'm not supposed to care, but apparently I do.)

I can't tell my customers they have to restore the print kernel after they installed MS Office? (suggestion in Google search)

There are two sides to it:

1. Sudden crashes in "commercial" SW is not acceptable
2. It doesn't look good with the title "Print" is exchanged  to the UWA Print Dialog (if Office is installed) "Printing from a Win32 program - Print", I like to find a way to put something in line with my program, to show my users.

Is there a new Win32 SDK feature that supports putting the title, preview and is crash free available? Something I can call instead of PrintDlgEx()?

Or are there other ways to handle the situation?

Comment: Certainly I could have input on how to introduce the UWA Print dialog with an MS Office 2021 installation. One gets the impression that there are old debug texts that the developer forgot to remove and obviously didn't test their work enough before the release of the UWA Print dialog. But honestly, I'm interested in getting the problem resolved. MS can take the follow-up of its development project of the UWA print dialog in-house, not with us. I don't mind UWA print dialogue. But then there must be a Win32 function call with title text and preview can be set in Win32. This is not unheard of.

Comment: Are you sure this is a 2nd chance exception and not a first chance? Microsoft is more and more using C++ exceptions internally and many of these are first chance that are caught also internally (but still visible in a debugger). In any case, you should be error to get the HRESULT that may give some insights about this. Otherwise, you should report Microsoft.

Comment: Done at MS Developer Community with the same title.

Comment: Well there must be a way to programatically communicate with the New Print Dialog extended features and be able to deliver previews etc that aren't in the traditional winapi?

Comment: Obviously this is an MSVC 2020 issue?

Comment: I doubt it's a compiler issue, but we can't say w/o some reproducible code.